# How to assign an id to an input with Elm and elm-mdl?

Tags: elm, material-design-lite

Is there a way to assign an `id` to an input (like a `Textfield`) with elm-mdl? I've tried the following:

```
Textfield.render Mdl [0] model.mdl
  [ Material.Options.id "my-id" ]
```

The problem is that assigns `my-id` as the `id` of the wrapping `<div>`:

```
<div id="my-id" class="mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield">
  <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" style="outline: none;">
</div>
```

I need for the actual `input` to have an `id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was answered by Michael Combs on his fork of elm-mdl. I completely overlooked `Options.inner` in the [package API docs for `Material.Options`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/MichaelCombs28/elm-mdl/1.0.1/Material-Options#inner):

```
Textfield.render Mdl [0] model.mdl
  [ Options.inner
    [ Options.id "my-id" ]
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

According to their documentation you could use [Material.Option.attribute](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/debois/elm-mdl/latest/Material-Options#attribute).

Try this:

```
Textfield.render Mdl [0] model.mdl
  [ Material.Options.attribute <| Html.Attributes.id "my-id"
  ]
```

Comment: a little lower on that page is the proper way to do it